# How to keep LyX from using babel?

Tags: lyx, babel

I'm writing a document using the `copernicus_discussions.cls` document class. This document class doesn't work when using `babel`. So I need to keep LyX from automatically using `babel`. However, even though in `Tools->Preferences->Language` I selected "Language package: None" and disabled all checkboxes on that page, and even though in my document preferences, I selected "Language package: None", the generated LaTeX source still contains the line

```
\usepackage{british,english]{babel}
```

How can I prevent LyX from inserting that line?

Comment: What's wrong with using `babel` with `natbib`?

Comment: as I wrote in the question, the `copernicus_discussions.cls` class doesn't work in conjunction with both natbib and babel. More specifically, LaTeX gets sent into an infinite loop at the first `\citet` or `\citep` command.

Comment: I just realized it also happens when using `\cite`, so it's not `natbib` dependant

Comment: There used to be a Lyx mailinglist, some years ago I got a usefull answer there, my question then also aimed at Lyx internals.

Comment: Links to LyX mailing lists are found at http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug that will be fixed with LyX 2.0.5

Workaround: In `Document Settings (Language)`, set language package to 
`Custom` and insert `% dummy` (or anything else preceded by a `%` char) into 
the custom package input widget.

[Related link](http://marc.info/?l=lyx-users&m=134882482914273&w=2)

Comment: Confirmed, the same still exists in LyX 2.2.3 (2017-05-17)

Comment: @sitilge I have LyX 2.2.3 as well, and that bug does not appear here. Setting the "Language Package" to "None" removes `babel` from the preamble.