# LyX: unable to display equation reference correctly with Latvian babel

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx, babel

I'm using Lyx and I want to have the reference format similar to

```
This is the reference to equation 2.1
```

My LaTex file is

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin4]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}

This is a formula
\begin{equation}
y\left(x\right)=x^{2}\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
This is a cross-reference \ref{eq:foo}
\end{document}
```

I've been trying different options, eg. changing the LaTex preamble, the document class, adding/removing modules like `Number Equations by Section`, etc. but nothing seems to work. What I can get is

```
2..1 => <Reference> on Page <Page>
2 => <Reference>
(2) => (<Reference>)
```

What should I do to get my equations in `<section>.<number>` format?

### UPDATE

The problem was caused by `\usepackage[latvian]{babel}`. Solution: [this SO question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74387/how-to-keep-lyx-from-using-babel/74492#comment986212_74492).

Comment: In a standard document (`article` class) adding the *Number Equations by Section* module is enough, the standard cross reference format (`<reference>`) will then give you `<section #>.<eq #>`.  Doesn't that work for you either?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Unfortunatelly, no. I thought that it would do the thing but, apparently, it has no effect on the output. The document class is Article (Standard Class). `<reference>` yields just the number inside the section.

Comment: That works here, so something is up. Can you make a small example document that demonstrates the problem (just a section, and equation, and a cross reference), and add the `.lyx` file to your question? A `.lyx` file is plain text file, so open it in any text editor and copy-paste the whole thing into your question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: It's the `latvian` `babel` that causes the problem, though I don't know why.